# Angular KendoGrid Header is not visible

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm implementing Kendo Grid with Angular. I'm able to bind the gridData and my rows are correctly mapped tot he grid, but the Column names or Headers of the grid are not visible as shown below

[image]

I need headers to be displayed and in my case the headers are dynamic which changes based on a dropdown present above the grid.

Please help me with missing configuration. Thank you!